# How to change default microphone input at Android devices?

Tags: usb, audio, camera, microphone, audio-recording

I have an android box (not tv box) that **doesn't have a built-in camera or mic**. I have connected Logitech c920 webcam via an USB port. (The android box: supports OTG port and jack 3,5 but I want to know if the connection is possible via a USB Camera).

The camera is compatible, but I can't hear anything, I can record only video. I have tried a lot of apps, but the only app that can recognise video and audio with tha same configuration is **USB Camera - Connect EasyCap or USB WebCam**. I want to enable mic from the webcam for almost every app.

Can I change the default microphone option somehow? Is this possible, if I change some settings, or with shell commands / or script / or app or any other way? Can anyone help?